# HtmlUnit/XPath find rows of table with caption

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

What's the right xpath here? I'm trying parse some html with HtmlUnit and am having trouble getting at the rows of a particular table. I want xpath to identify the table via a caption element and return me a list of rows.

```
<html> 
  <table> 
    <caption>table1</caption>  
    <tr><td>cell 1.1</td><td>cell 1.2</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>cell 2.1</td><td>cell 2.2</td></tr> 
  </table>  
  <table> 
    <caption>table2</caption>  
    <tr><td>cell 1-1</td><td>cell 1-2</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>cell 2-1</td><td>cell 2-2</td></tr> 
  </table> 
</html>
```

The xpath I thought should work is "//caption['table2']/parent::table/tr" but an online tester ends up returning all rows in both tables, not just the one with the target caption. But then using HtmlUnit in my own java test is returning an empty list. That line of code is:

```
final List<HtmlTableRow> domNodeList = (List<HtmlTableRow>) page.getByXPath("//caption['table2']/parent::table/tr");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go down to caption only to find table.

```
//table[caption='table2']/tr
```

Comment: Cool - that works in the online tester, but my HtmlUnit code is still returning am empty list. What's the right code there (anyone)?

Comment: Consider trying the path step by step:

Does "//table" return a list of tables?

Does "//table[caption='table2']" return a list with just one required table?

Comment: Good tip - the two table ones you cited work as expected. It returns null once I added the final "/tr". I didn't get a chance to troubleshoot further yet, but will tonite.

Comment: I've just got an idea: probably your xpath must include tbody, which is an implicit element inside of the table. //table[caption='table2']/tbody/tr

Comment: Yep, that's it. Mostly Mostacho's answer explains the why of it. I wish I could pick both as correct but I'll upvote both.

Answer (score 1):

Never try to use XPath in HtmlUnit by looking at the source code of the page. You should:

1. Get the page
2. Output the content using `asXml()`
3. Build the XPath expression based on that

HtmlUnit modifies the source code of the page. And it is not just a matter of beautifying it but actually modifying it. EG: Adding `tbody` as well as many other changes. So I bet that is not the output from HtmlUnit itself.

Follow the previous steps and you should get it working.